# Batch scripting

Tags: command-line, script

Trying to sort a family album jpegs into folders

I sorted an Excel sheet with picture IDs belonging to family member into two different columns

columns A it is picture ID and column b is family name

there are several pictures belonging to one family member and I'm trying to create a script that will move all the pictures based on the family ID. I named all the pictures with a number making it very easy

I am new to scripting and I thought I would give this a try I'm very good with Excel but not with scripting using the command prompt

My family would be grateful

Comment: Probably a question for StackOverflow

Comment: This is a job for powershell, not a batch file.

Comment: Hey user. Welcome to superuser. Two things. The first is that your title is not very descriptive of your issue. "Batch scripting" is very broad. Using a more descriptive title will help draw interest to your question and improves the likelihood of your finding an answer. Second, I agree with @appleoddity PowerShell is much more capable. DOS/CMD (the interpreter for batch files) is extremely old (decades) and outdated and has a large number of confusing syntax it has picked up over the years. And yet it's still rather limited on what it can do.

Comment: I agree. PowerShell is better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example.vbs file

```
sourcefolder = "C:\Users\1074493\Documents\images\" 'Where your images are
set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject") 
set folder = fso.getfolder(sourcefolder)

for each file in folder.files
fileName = fso.getbasename(file)
'wscript.echo file
'wscript.echo fileName

if fileName = "10" then 'family ID

fso.MoveFile file, "C:\Users\1074493\Documents\" 'Which folder the picture is going to

end if

next
```

Here is the run.bat file

```
cscript example.vbs
```

Open the run.bat file which will execute the VBScript to run in Command Prompt!

This example say's if the file name is 10 then move it!

Comment: Thanks for the vbs script. I have some questions. The images are in different folders and there is a csv file that has the image name related to the family ID. How do I get the script to know what is the picture association to the family ID and lastly, I would like to sort the pictures into folder that are name to the family ID. Thanks

Comment: I will write it another day, kinda sick bro!